# sonar+github integration

Tags: github, sonarqube

I want to enable sonar with git but is it neccesary that first pull the project from git repository using hudson or something else and then sonar will analyse the code periodically on hudson .am I right means my steps :

1.Pull project from git using hudson.

2.Sonar on hudson will analyse the code and send the updates.?

or directly we can use git+sonar how it works ,can anybody guide me to get it work.

Comment: The answer is good, but Sonar should make it easier. It's such a good tool, it's a pity is not better integrated with github. [Coveralls](https://coveralls.io/) did it great for instance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you need first to pull your project from GitHub, and then launch a Sonar analysis on your local copy (Sonar needs the file to exist on the file system to be able to analyse them).

So you can pull your project manually or obvioulsy using a CI server like Jenkins/Hudson.

Comment: can we done it without using hudson? if yes how we can do it, am really unaware about this.

Comment: You can write you own script that does "git pull + mvn sonar:sonar", and schedule that script using the cron table (Unix/Linux) or the task scheduler (Windows). However, I'd advise you to prefer Hudson/Jenkins, those are far more powerful.

Comment: ok... thanks, means I just need to install the sonar plugin on hudson and configure a job over there. am i right?

Comment: Yes, see the documentation here: http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=116359341 (and please validate this answer if that answered your question!)

Answer (score 3):

The good news, yesterday (2015-07-08) SonarQube has launched a Github Pluging, every time a pull request is submitted, the CI system launches a SonarQube preview analysis.

**Reference:**
http://www.sonarqube.org/github-pull-request-analysis-helps-fix-the-leak/

Comment: This is inaccurate, the plugin does not make the CI system do anything. All it does is push results of an analysis to the PR, but that analysis has to be launched by the CI, which is your job. Easy with Jenkins (PRBuilder), no so with Bamboo.